# Oracle Report 6i: Report crashes when called from a Form

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a report made with Oracle reports 6i (I didn't make it and it has a lot of operations in it), and when I call the report from a form, it crashes and closes.

I'm trying to figure out where the problem comes from. In order to do that, I used ***report Triggers*** (in each trigger I'm showing a message):

- Before parameter form: `srw.message(10,'before parameter form');` **(the message shows)**
- After parameter form: `srw.message(10,'After parameter form');` **(It shows)**
- Before report: `srw.message(10,'before report');` **(It shows)**
- Between pages: `srw.message(10,'Between pages');` **(It doesn't show anything)**
- After report: `srw.message(10,'after report');` **(It doesn't show anything)**

I tried to show a message in each ***program Unit***, but only the ones that are in margin section that work, I don't know where the problem comes from.

What can I do to know the source of the crashing? anything would be helpful!

Comment: did you try to recompile ALL (Ctrl + Shift + K) both form & report?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes i tried and the same problem occurs

Comment: I *hate* Reports. The only version that worked properly was 1.1, the rest is getting worse from version to version. I don't know why it crashes. If possible, try to run its query (or all of them, if possible) in SQLPlus or some other, GUI tool you use. Make sure you get **all** rows, not only the first 100 or 500. If they raise an error, you'll be closer to solution. Then, fomula columns - create (stored) functions using that code and include them into SELECTs. Too bad that it is a complex report; could be virtually *anything* that causes it to close ...

Comment: have you tried looking at http://hostname.domain:port/reports/rwservlet/showjobs?server=yourreportserver look for jobs that have a red cross and click on it, will sometimes give you some useful information... not always but could be worth a look